# How can i take this navigation bar up?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.abc {
 width:600px;
 height:120px;
 background-color:yellow;
 display:inline-block;
}
ul{
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 }
ul li {
 display:inline;
 font-size:24px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="abc">
<img src="../../../Desktop/254014_208382935867586_7113053_n.jpg" width="180" height="120" />
<ul >
<li><a href="www.quora.com">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="www.quora.com">gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="www.quora.com">about us</a></li>
<li><a href="www.quora.com">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to take this navigation bar up( on alignment of middle of the logo). How to do this? 
I am new to html/css as well new to stack overflow.

Comment: Try to make the image `display: block;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 `<nav>` tag, and [FlexBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) box model to achieve this.

Here is the a live [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/3png37r2/).

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <img src="path/to/my/logo" width="180" height="100%">
    <a href="#">home</a>
    <a href="#">gallery</a>
    <a href="#">about us</a>
    <a href="#">contact</a>     
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0 !important;
}
nav{
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    background-color: rgb(21, 138, 194);
}
nav > a{
    margin: 0 1em;

    display: flex;

    color: #036088;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav > a:hover{
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you can set the margin of your page to 0, making the elements on the very border of the page.

Add like below :

```
*{
margin:0px;
}
```

This will set all the content of your page with a 0 margin. The `*` selector matches every element in your html page.

Answer (score 0):

Set the 'vertical-align' property on the image in the navbar to 'middle'.

This will align any other inline elements next to that image relative to the image's vertical center.

This link describes how the vertical-align property works https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

```css
.abc {
  width:600px;
  height:120px;
  background-color:yellow;
  display:inline-block;
}
ul {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

ul li {
  display:inline;
  font-size:24px;
}

/* THIS IS THE ONLY NEW CODE */
.abc img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="abc">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" width="180" height="120" />
    <ul>
      <li><a href="www.quora.com">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="www.quora.com">gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="www.quora.com">about us</a></li>
      <li><a href="www.quora.com">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is capture page elements within div tags and play with margins...

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>

.bar{
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: -95px;
}

.abc {
    width:600px;
    height:120px;
    background-color:yellow;
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
 }
 ul{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
 }
 ul li {
    display:inline;
    font-size:24px;  
 }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="abc">
  <div class="Image"><img  src="../../../Desktop/254014_208382935867586_7113053_n.jpg" width="180"  height="120" /></div>
  <div class="bar">
  <ul >
  <li><a href="www.quora.com">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.quora.com">gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.quora.com">about us</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.quora.com">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

want something like this right? :)

[image]